# PHP fatal error on server after deactivating modules

Tags: 7, migrations

Today our site went down with only white pages showing. The logs from the nginx server looks like this:

```
[01-Sep-2016 10:33:15] WARNING: [pool www0] child 26970 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MigrateSimpleFieldHandler' not found in /srv/www/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/entityreference/entityreference.migrate.inc on line 18"
[01-Sep-2016 10:33:15] WARNING: [pool www0] child 26970 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MigrateUIWizard' not found in /srv/www/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/migrate_d2d/migrate_d2d_ui/migrate_d2d_ui.migrate.inc on line 18"
[01-Sep-2016 10:33:20] WARNING: [pool www1] child 26712 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class name must be a valid object or a string in /srv/www/mysite/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 8026"
[01-Sep-2016 10:33:24] WARNING: [pool www1] child 26710 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class name must be a valid object or a string in /srv/www/mysite/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 8026"
[01-Sep-2016 10:34:27] WARNING: [pool www1] child 27190 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class name must be a valid object or a string in /srv/www/mysite/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 8026"
[01-Sep-2016 10:34:40] WARNING: [pool www1] child 26712 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class name must be a valid object or a string in /srv/www/mysite/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 8026"
[01-Sep-2016 10:34:56] WARNING: [pool www0] child 23319 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class name must be a valid object or a string in /srv/www/mysite/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 8026"
```

This happens as soon as I try to update the database, I also get a "502 Bad Gateway" message from the server just before the screen turns white.

Should I activate the deactivated modules again or uninstall them?

EDITED: I can also mention that according to the status report there are database updates waiting to be run, but when I do that locally (wamp) I get the message that no database update is required. When I try to do this db update on the web server (nginx) I get 502 bad gateway error and then the pages go blank.

Comment: `NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MigrateSimpleFieldHandler' not found` have you deleted any of the module before uninstalling it?

Comment: No I haven't deleted any modules. Just disabled them. And by doing that the classes mentioned cannot be found.. Maybe it's best just to enable them again.

Comment: Have you a backup from before the modules were deactivated? I'd work from that if possible. Also, you say there are updates waiting. Check the list on update.php to see what modules the updates belong to. Is Core up to date? I got handed a site running a very early version of D7, and to update to the latest core I had to upgrade one version at a time, running update.php after each, or I'd just get WSOD (I'm sure there are key versions that could be applied, but this worked).

Comment: That's just it. On update.php there is no list (how can I see which modules needs updating?) and when I run the update I get a message saying that no updates are required. Then in the status report, the message is still that I urgently need to run database updates for several modules. I have run cron multiple times too, without luck. I do all this locally now, I don't dare touch the live web site.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem is solved thanks to [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/1263908#comment-11570249).
The database update wasn't possible for the Field collection module (but it could have been any number of modules), but with the help of all the people that contributed to the solution in the thread above, I was able to get the db update to run as expected. After that everything seems to work.